# Delete randomly generated button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

`-(void)createTurtle` is a timer-action

```
-(void)createTurtle {
     NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(284) + 1;

     int storedIntegerFromTurtle = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"savedTurtleTag"];

     turtle = [[UIButton alloc] init];
     turtle.frame = CGRectMake(r, -50, 36, 47);
     [turtle setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"turtle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [turtle addTarget:self action:@selector(turtleTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
     [turtle setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [turtle setTag:storedIntegerFromTurtle+1];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:turtle];
     [self.view addSubview:turtle];


     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:turtle.tag forKey:@"savedTurtleTag"];
     NSLog(@"%i", turtle.tag);


     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:15];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

     turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, 36, 47);
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And by tapping on it I will delete the selected button:

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     CGPoint p =[((UITouch *)[touches anyObject]) locationInView:self.view];
     CGRect r= [turtle.layer.presentationLayer frame];

     int selectedTurtleTag;

     if (CGRectContainsPoint(r, p))
     {
         selectedTurtleTag = turtle.tag;
     }

     BOOL contains= CGRectContainsPoint(r, p);
     if(contains)
     {
         if (turtle.tag == selectedTurtleTag )
         {
             NSLog(@"Turtle-Tag: %i", selectedTurtleTag);
             [[self.view viewWithTag:selectedTurtleTag] removeFromSuperview];
         }
     }
}
```

My problem is that i only can remove the latest created button.
And i would remove any button which is clicked.

Comment: Why don't you create an array to hold all the `turtle`s.  Then you can get a handle to any of them without having to use the tag notation.  The delete whatever you wish from the array and screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a property called turtle.  When you create a random turtle the instance variable is referencing that turtle only because at that time you are freshly alloc/initing it.  So, the last created turtle will always be called turtle and that is why this only works on the last one (you use turtle.tag, and at that point turtle is only the last one.)  I would suggest an NSMutableArray of turtles and adding the newly created turtle to the array in createTurtle; then loop through your array of turtles in touchesBegan to find which turtle was tapped.

Comment: Great! Thank you. It works! Sorry for my bad english but i'm from germany